# SSRS Date parameter function - Mid Month

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2

We run a report every month.. 1-15th and then 16th-EOM..

I want to have the report calculate the start & end date parameter based on the day..

So if I open the report between the 1-15 it will put for this month.. 11/1/2015 start date and 11/15/2015 end date.  After the 15th.. 11/16/2015-11/30/2015 (EOM).

I was going to use an iif statement to find the day then use something like this.

```
=FormatDateTime(DatePart("m",Now()) & "/16/" & DatePart("yyyy",Now()), DateFormat.ShortDate)
```

when I put that in the expression of the parameter I get an invalid type.

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using "/16/" as a string, you wind up with a string after concatenating the dateparts, and the FormatDateTime function expects a date input. Wrap the date in a cdate() function.

```
=FormatDateTime(cdate(DatePart("m",Now()) & "/16/" & DatePart("yyyy",Now()), DateFormat.ShortDate)))
```

On a slightly higher level, why format to a short date at all, since you already have the date as a string?

Comment: Thanks that is what I needed to point me in the right direction.. I was just trying several things on the dateformat.. here is what I used.


    =IIf(DatePart("m",Now()) > 15,CDate(DatePart("m",Now()) & "/16/" & DatePart("yyyy",Now())), CDate(DatePart("m",Now()) & "/1/" & DatePart("yyyy",Now())))

=IIf(DatePart("m",Now()) < 16,CDate(DatePart("m",Now()) & "/15/" & DatePart("yyyy",Now())), DateSerial(Year(Now()), Month(Now()), "1").AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1))

Comment: I cant seem to figure out how to make it mark for code.. sorry.